# Merge changes from parent branch

Tags: mercurial

I created a branch for a new feature, and now i want to pull in any changes from the parent branch/baseline?

How can I do this?
Is there a way for me to see what will get merged before I actually merge?

```
--baseline
  --> my branch
```

I want to pull in any changes to 'my branch' from baseline.

Comment: Show glog output of your (single?) repo!

Answer (score 3):

If you have unsynced changes (see them with `hg incoming`), you will have to pull first:

```
hg pull
```

Then do the merge:

```
hg up my-branch; hg merge baseline
```

You can now inspect your merge result using `hg diff`, `hg status`, etc

You can allways cancel the merge by doing a `hg up --clean`

If the merge is ok, then you must commit the result:

```
hg ci -m 'Merging baseline into my-branch'
```

Answer (score 2):

Both previous answers are possible erroneous in the direct interpretation of the terms.

Branch created in **the same repo usually**, "pulling" from "baseline" to "my branch" *can be really* **merge**

Merge

```
hg up mybranch 
hg merge baseline
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the changes from the baseline (parent).

```
hg pull
```

You can view what changed with a log command:

```
hg log -P
```

Then you can merge the changes locally and push back to the baseline. This is all covered in [Joel's tutorial](http://hginit.com/04.html).